# How to catch google search parameters for chrome extension - evernote-like simultaneous search

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-search, evernote

I am currently playing around with chrome extensions. I would like to catch google search parameters (i.e. the keyword query) and use them to display other stuff as the [evernote extension](http://blog.evernote.com/2010/09/30/evernote-chrome-extension-gets-simultaneous-search/) does.

Does anybody have an idea how they implemented it?

Have been looking at the source code for quite a while now and couldn't find anything.

Comment: It looks like they're just injecting their own code into the SERP

Comment: yeah, the more difficult problem for me is how they get access to the keyword query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the search term is the q parameter of the search url, so in a background page you could monitor tabs and then use parseUri (http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) to parse the url and get q.
Something like this...
**background.js**

```
// make sure you include the parseUri listed above
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) 
    {
        uri = parseUri(tab.url);
        if ((uri.host.indexOf('google')!=-1)&&(uri.path=='/search')){
            // do something with the search term
            console.debug('Search term was : ' + unescape(uri.queryKey.q));
        }

    });
```